# Logback dbappender delete db when start up

Tags: logback

I want to delete data in logback db tables (logging_event, logging_event_property, logging_event_exceptions) when engine starts.

As far as I know, `append = false` param was what I am looking for.
Like this;

`<append>false</append>`

It works in `filedappender`, `consoleappender`, **but it does not work in `dbappender`.**

How can I delete the data when engine start to run?

Comment: What did you find in the API documentation?

Comment: <append>false</append>   It works correctly in fileappender, consoleappender. But it does not work in dbappender.